# Select dropdown not working in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I had written a sample code for select dropdown, in case of Edge browser the drop down is not working, i.e. it is not allow to select the option from the drop down. Below is the sample code

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
  <option value="https://www.amazon.in/">Amazon</option>
  <option value="https://www.flipkart.com/">Flipkart</option>
  <option value="http://www.snapdeal.com/">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
```

in case of other browsers it working fine. Please help me out how can I solve this issue?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: in edge browser, its now allowing to select the drop down elements, even after clicking on the dropdown elements.

Comment: Could you possible post some more code, maybe that whole segment, and maybe your CSS as well?

Comment: add a jsfiddle so that we can identify the problem

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue, try turning off JS then testing your site. If that doesn't work it could be a CSS issue, so try disabling your styles and testing it. Without more code it's hard to establish, the problem is almost certainly not the select HTML but something else.

Comment: I have this issue also. I only use Edge when inside Windows Mixed Reality Portal. Else I use Chrome. When inside WMR Portal, the select opens and shows it options, but I cannot select an option.

Comment: @Viira No need. Stack snippets, built into the question editor, can do the same thing without making us visit another site

Answer (score 0):

Please add <select> open tag. [Preview In Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz4lb.png)

```html
<select>
<option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
<option value="https://www.amazon.in/">Amazon</option>
<option value="https://www.flipkart.com/">Flipkart</option>
<option value="http://www.snapdeal.com/">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the same code only iam using with select open and closing tag, but it not woking, Actually its not allowing to select the dropdown items.

Comment: I think this gonna be happened you browser. Please follow the below steps.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/microsoft-edge-drop-down-menus-not-working/e70bb7b7-5336-490b-8099-a1b5dfa4fe82

Comment: thank you @ Asela Jayathissa, i followed the those things also but  the problem is still persisting

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a `<select>` opening tag.

Comment: in edge browser, its now allowing to select the drop down elements, even after clicking on the dropdown elements.